# Redirect is not working with query string parameters in browser on iis after secure https has been set up

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have set iis up so that http redirects to https which is working as it should. The problem is that if I type the url into the browser without http - such as:
example.com/page.aspx?id=1 then it redirects without the parameters - like this:
https://example.com/page.aspx

I am sure that it is some problem in the way iis is redirecting from http to https because if I look in chrome debugger then the url is changed to:
https://example.com/page.aspx
so this happens before my asp.net page is even called.

I have no rewrite rules in my web.config file instead I am using my own class that inherits from IHttpModule:

```
class LinkModule : IHttpModule
{
    string realQueryString = "";
    public LinkModule()
    {
    }
    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.BeginRequest += new EventHandler(context_BeginRequest);
    }
    public void Dispose() { }
    private void context_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpRequest request = ((HttpApplication)sender).Request;
        HttpContext context = ((HttpApplication)sender).Context;
        string applicationPath = request.ApplicationPath;
        string requestPath = request.Url.AbsolutePath.Substring(applicationPath.Length);
        string path = HttpContext.Current.Request.Path;
        //string host = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_HOST"];
        realQueryString = context.Request.QueryString.ToString();
        string requesturi = request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Substring(applicationPath.Length);
        LoadTemplate(ref requestPath);
        context.RewritePath(applicationPath + requestPath);
    }
    private void LoadTemplate(ref string path)
    {
        if (path.IndexOf("showproduct.aspx", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) != -1)
        {
            path = string.Format("/frontarea/product/index{0}", !string.IsNullOrEmpty(realQueryString) ? "?" + realQueryString : "");
            return;
        }         
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please add your rewrite rules from web.config

Comment: I have no rewrite rules in my web.config file instead I am using my own class that inherits from IHttpModule. I have now added the class code. Hopefully this will help.